# Toast. Can not chain methods, but also can not invoke it in a normal way?

Tags: android

```
Toast.makeText(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);

Toast.show();
```

This code doesnt work. Toast.show() is marked in red with the following error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method show() from the type Toast
```

---

```
Toast.makeText(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, 
        configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0)
            .show();
```

This also doesnt work, giving me the following error:

```
Cannot invoke show() on the primitive type void
```

Comment: Are the odd backticks in the last example just messed up markdown, or is that your actual code?

Comment: just messed up markdown, not actual code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show is not a static method, so you need to use the instance you create with the makeText method. This is how you could do it:

```
Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
myToast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

show() method is not a static method,So you cant call Toast.show();

Rather you  should use following.

```
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);

toast.show();
```